# Why does this for loop not iterate through all lists in the array

Tags: python, for-loop

I wrote this for loop but it does not show the expected behavior.

```
list_of_lists = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

element = 4

for lst in list_of_lists:
    if lst.index(element):
        found = lst.index(element)
        print "success"
        print found
        break
```

The desired outcome should be that the loop gives found = list_of_lists[1][0].
However, it only evaluates the first list in the array not the second.
In case the search key is in another then list_of_lists[0]
the error I get is.

```
   if lst.index(element):
ValueError: 4 is not in list
```

Thanks for you help guys!

Comment: Could that `break` statement at the bottom have something to do with it?

Comment: lst.index(4)=0, hence false

Comment: Actually, `lst.index(4)` would raise a `ValueError` (for the first list).

Comment: I have suggested how to improve your `if` statement in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because it breaks out of the `for` loop. Just remove that statement (and make some changes to your `if` statement:

```
list_of_lists = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
element = 4

for lst in list_of_lists:
    if element in lst:
        print lst.index(element)
        print "success"
    else:
        print "Not Contained"
```

Comment: It never enters the if conditional unless lst.index(4) is true though, so why would the break matter?

Comment: @Human, I have suggested an update to the code. Answer updated

Comment: That makes sense now, I think that was the original problem, anyway.

Comment: okay I see and understand thanks very much for the swift reply.

Comment: @user3217612, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you

Comment: @enigma, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you